# Comparison test on $ \int_2 ^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t^{3/2}} \ dt$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

How would one use the comparison test to deduce whether the following function converges or diverges?
I’ve attempted to use $ \ln(t) < t $ for $ t > 1$ but fail to conclude whether the desired function converges.
I’ve also attempted to use $ \ln (t) > 1 $ for $ t > e $ but also encounter a similar issue once again.

Comment: Try $\ln t < 4t^{1/4}$? (Which, incidentally, follows from $\ln u < u$ by taking $u=t^{1/4}$)

Comment: How can one demonstrate it holds true?

Comment: @DogukanKayhan In general, $lnx$ "loses" against any $x^n$ (assuming n>0) for large values of $x$. So choose a suitable $n$ such that the difference between $n$ and the power of the denominator is still greater than $1$ to have convergence

Comment: Thank you Imran, very helpful comment - thank you for posting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard trick is use limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{t^{\alpha}} $ for $1<\alpha<\frac32$, as for example by the convergent

$$\int_2 ^\infty \frac{1}{t^{5/4}} \ dt$$

indeed as $x\to \infty$

$$\frac{\frac{\ln t}{t^{3/2}}}{\frac{1}{t^{5/4}} }=\frac{\ln t}{t^{1/4}}\to 0 $$

and thus the given integral converges.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: @DogukanKayhan You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to know whether $\int_2^\infty t^{-3/2}\ln t \,dt=\int_{\ln 2}^\infty ue^{-u/2}\,du$ converges. Well, it does because $\int_{\ln 2}^\infty ue^{-u/2}\,du\in \left[0,\,\int_0^\infty ue^{-u/2}\,du\right]=\left[0,\,\frac{1!}{(1/2)^2}\right]=[0,\,4]$.

Comment: Thank you, but how would one use the comparison test to prove it?

Comment: @DogukanKayhan It depends how broadly you construe comparison. In this case, our integrand on $u\ge 0$ is $ue^{-u/2}[u\ge \ln 2]$, where the brackets denote an Iverson bracket. You could compare this to $ue^{-u/2}$, $ue^{-2u/3}$ etc., but such choices will tend to invoke convergence results whose proofs are nearly identical to the above, so that the use of a comparison is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes it does indeed become trivial. Cheers.